# web parts closed

Tags: asp.net

can anyone  please tell me...
once  have closed a webpart when i am running my application again it is not displaying the webparts...i have to place my code in to other webpart....
so please tell me the solution...why it s happening....and to prevent from creating the webpart again an d again.....

thanks....

Answer (score 1):

If I can realize your problem, you need a [PageCatalogPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.pagecatalogpart.aspx) control that displays the closed web parts. Check the following article out.

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/06/27/webparts_3.html